# Can't read data with Apache Kafka and Debezium from federated MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using Apache Kafka and Debezium's connector service to see data changes in my tables. Also I'm using AWS EC2 where I have a Database with federated tables. If I created a no federated table, and run my docker watcher with Zookeeper, Kafka and Kafka Connect up, I can read data from that table, but when I'm seeing a federated table, can't read data.

I tried to add a query in my connector's configuration, but that doesn's work.

My commands are:

#### Start Zookeeper

`$ docker run -it --rm --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper:0.9`

#### Start Kafka

`$ docker run -it --rm --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka:0.9`

#### Start Kafka Connect

`$ docker run -it --rm --name connect -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka debezium/connect:0.9`

#### Register a connector

`$ curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{ "name": "inventory-connector", "config": { "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector", "tasks.max": "1", "database.hostname": "mysql", "database.port": "3306", "database.user": "debezium", "database.password": "dbz", "database.server.id": "184054", "database.server.name": "dbserver1", "database.whitelist": "inventory", "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.inventory" } }'`

#### Show data changes

`$ docker run -it --name watcher --rm --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka debezium/kafka:0.9 watch-topic -a -k dbserver1.inventory.customers`

I expect to see something like that:

```
null    {"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":true,"field":"a1"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"a2"}],"optional":true,"name":"dbserver1.cobranza.foobar_1.Value","field":"before"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":true,"field":"a1"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"a2"}],"optional":true,"name":"dbserver1.cobranza.foobar_1.Value","field":"after"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"version"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"connector"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"name"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"server_id"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"ts_sec"},
...
```

Comment: `"database.hostname": "mysql"`? That's not a proper EC2 hostname... Look at the errors/logs/status of the connector

Comment: Exactly. Could you please check the log of the `connect` container?

Comment: @cricket_007 "mysql" it was the name of my container where i had running my database, it was a example from Debezium's tutorial, but my real value is the ip of my database. My connector's status show RUNNING for task and connector.

Comment: @JiriPechanec the output of my connect container is:
`INFO: Connected to 54.156.164.250:3306 at mysql-bin.000059/154 (sid:184053, cid:21287)
2019-07-03 15:32:37,602 INFO   ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=connector-cobranza-1-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask]`
But, when I run the watcher command, doesn't show nothing...

Answer (score 0):

looking at the `FEDERATED` engine description https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html it seems to me that the changes made to the federated table are not recorded in server binlog file. If it is the case then Debezium cannot stream the changes as it does not see them.

It should be able to stream changes from the source table.